# How to update android/ios app programatically with flutter when new version uploaded in to appstore/playstore

Tags: android, ios, flutter

** I want to update my flutter app (ios/android) programatically when new version uploaded in to google PlayStore/AppStore with in the application window i need to show the dialogbox. Is there any packages or plugins for this. **

Answer (score 1):

You can create a PHP API where return a play store app version code. Then receive a json from Android/iPhone. Compare with app version to PHP API return version. If PHP version is bigger than app version then show alert dialog.
When you upload new application in play store change API version code.

Comment: You probably don't even need all that.  Just make a github page that has the version number, and edit it when you update your code.